# font color in .doc MS-word using tcl+html

Tags: html, linux, ms-word, tcl, mime

I send report files (automation result) in .doc format attachment to email accounts.
I use TCL 8.5, expect, html and MIME to send email from a Fedora 12 server.

I could see the result fonts in color (Eg "Pass" in green and "Fail" in Red) in

1. my email body,
2. My CLI terminal, and also
3. When opening the .doc file with openoffice on linux/windows.

However, when I try opening the same file using MS-Word I don't see color text rather I see the HTML code with the text. Please Guide. I am not using TK and I tried installing the pdf4tcl08 as suggested by Stalwarts but its not getting installed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The variations in the DOC format are absolutely horrible. Alas, you need an expert on that side of things, which is definitely not me.

Comment: @Donal has it got something to do with the encoding stuff like utf etc? Please tell me how to install the pdf4tcl on my Fedora 12. Thank you.